# Every subpace of $V/U$ is of the form $W/U$

Tags: linear-algebra

> If $V$ is a vector space, $W$ a subspace of it, then every subpace of $V/U$ is of the form $W/U$, with $U\subset W\subset V$

How can I write $V/U$, if $U$ were a coset then Ok, but here it is just a subset

Comment: well, I guess, $U$ is assumed to be a *subspace* (hence also a coset).

Comment: In Linear Algebra, $V/U$ and $W/U$ are only defined when $U$ is a linear subspace.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Ok thanks, then If I use the theorem of orthogonal complement, I'm done but it requires that $V$ should be finite dimensional,  I don't see here why it matters ?

Answer (score 0):

Given a linear subspace $U$ of $V$, let $q$ be the quotient map taking $V$ to $V/U$.  Suppose $L$ is a linear subspace of $V/U$, and let $W = q^{-1}(L) = \{x \in V: q(x) \in L\}$.  Show that $W$ is a linear subspace of $V$ containing $U$, and that $L = q(W)$.